# Group Validation of Two DateTime Picker Using Javascript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Group Validation of Two DateTime Picker Using Javascript in asp.net

Comment: This is still not a question, please reformulate...

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I here is what I am thinking. You have 2 textboxes, each has a DateTime picker wired up to it, either via the AjaxControlToolkit, or JQuery UI (or similar framework).

In order to validate those, you can assign a class name (date) eg:

and validate this via the JQuery Validate plugin. It uses class names to create custom validation for specific input formats, etc... There is also the capability to use your own regular expression with it, and therefore customize it to your specific needs.